# Error when downloading file through ADODB stream in VB code

Tags: xmlhttprequest, vb6

We are getting an error message "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" when opening an ADODB stream object for downloading a file automatically on the user's computer. The error is on the line  `objADOStream.Open`  and `objADOStream.Write .GetReponseBody` and we are using the following lines of code:

```
Private Sub oXMLHTTP_ResponseReady(ByVal ready As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo oXMLHTTP_ResponseReady_EH
    Call WriteLog("ready:" & ready & ", OutFilePathName:" & OutFilePathName, "oXMLHTTP_ResponseReady")
    Dim objADOStream As Object
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject 'comment
      If ready Then
          With oXMLHTTP
              If fs.FileExists(OutFilePathName) = True Then fs.DeleteFile (OutFilePathName)
              Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
              'timer disable 'timerlastdat
              TmrLastDataArrival.Enabled = False 'comment
              objADOStream.Open
              objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
              objADOStream.Write .GetReponseBody
              objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start
              objADOStream.SaveToFile OutFilePathName
              objADOStream.Close
              Set objADOStream = Nothing
          End With
          bDownloading = False
      End If
      Set fs = Nothing
```

Please assist in resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `oXMLHTTP` is an instance of  `IXMLHTTPRequest`, then there is no method or property called `GetResponseBody`. However, there's a property `responseBody`.

And as far as I can tell, you simply store the web request's response to disk, for which I think using the ADODB.Stream object is overkill. Why not simply use VB's file handling commands (`Open OutFilePathName As #...`)? It takes 4 lines of code to do so:

```
   Dim hFile As Long: hFile = FreeFile
   Open OutFilePathName For Binary Access Write Shared As #hFile
   Put #hFile, , oXMLHTTP.responseBody
   Close #hFile
```